# Is it possible to connect more than one IBM MQ queue manager in the same same process?

Tags: ibm-mq

Based on IBM MQ doc, I need to define a environment variable named `MQSERVER` for the MQ server address. So in one process, can I only have one MQ server address, is it correct?

Is there any other way to define MQ server address and have multiple MQ connections to different MQ servers?

Comment: Coding for MQ client now (C/C++), is it possible to have multiple threads(clients) to connect to different mq servers in one process?

Comment: Look at CCDT client channel definition tables.   They can hold details for many queue managers.   You can also programmatically specify connection details in c++.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, JoshMc. 
Do you mean specify connection details in MQCNO?
But I do not find how to specify the server address in MQCNO.
How can I specify server address without using MQSERVER env variable?

Comment: You specify the channel name, host, and port in the `MQCD` which is referenced from the `MQCNO`.  In C it is the `MQCONNX` call that allows this.  If you specify things in the CCDT then you point to the CCDT with `MQCHLLIB=/path/to/table` and `MQCHLTAB=table_filename.TAB`, then you can issue a normal `MQCONN` (or MQCONNX) call and specify just the queue manager name.  It will find this QMNAME in the CCDT and use the connection details provided in the CCDT.

Comment: Great, I will use the MQCD.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the channel name, host, and port in the `MQCD` which is referenced from the `MQCNO`. In C you would pass this to the `MQCONNX` function.

You can also specify connection details (channel name, host, and port) in a CCDT (Client Channel Definition Table).  You would point to the CCDT with the following environment variables (there are other ways but this is one way):

```
MQCHLLIB=/path/to/table
MQCHLTAB=table_filename.TAB
```

You could then use `MQCONN` (or `MQCONNX`) and specify just the queue manager name. MQ will find an entry in the CCDT that matches the queue manager name and use the connection details provided.

Answer (score -2):

You specify the channel name, host, and port in the MQCD which is referenced from the MQCNO. In C it is the MQCONNX call that allows this. If you specify things in the CCDT then you point to the CCDT with MQCHLLIB=/path/to/table and MQCHLTAB=table_filename.TAB, then you can issue a normal MQCONN (or MQCONNX) call and specify just the queue manager name. It will find this QMNAME in the CCDT and use the connection details provided in the CCDT. – JoshMc 21 mins ago

Comment: If my comment helps you I would appreciate the opportunity to post it as answer that you could accept rather than you just copying and pasting it into an answer.  Does this work for you?

Comment: See my answer, you can always delete your answer which was a copy of my comment by clicking the delete link under it.

Comment: Did you see my comments above?  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you! set up the user and password in MQCD and it work for me now.